# why wp_title filter is not working at all?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know there are other questions like this but didn't find a reliable answer. So:

First activate the thing (simplyfied code):

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
function theme_setup() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
}
```

Second, delete title tag from header.php.

Third, on page templates, before calling `get_header()`, add something like this:

```
  add_filter('wp_title', 'set_custom_title', 10, 3);
  function set_custom_title($title, $sep, $seplocation){
    return 'test';
  }
```

Well, this is not working at all, in any template, being a page, an archive, a custom taxonomy or post type archive. No nothing. Wordpress is generating titles by itself.

Why? Am I doing something wrong? Note that this code once upon a time just worked: used in other sites/themes.

Is it maybe an issue of wp5.2.0?

Comment: add this code in header.php `<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?> | <?php echo get_bloginfo('name') ?></title>
`

Comment: @Vel, it works, thank you. But quite strange, since once upon a time it was a no-no... You had to delete the title tag from head in order to make the filter work... Bah..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to @Vel, the answer is to re-add the title tag (even if in previous wp versions > don't know til what version you had to delete it form head instead).

Current working code for me:

```
//functions.php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
function theme_setup() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
}

//header.php
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?> | <?php echo get_bloginfo('name') ?></title>

//page templates
$window_title = // do something
add_filter('wp_title', function($title, $sep, $seplocation) use($window_title){ return $window_title; }, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case Yoast SEO was changing the way title was rendered and only the following worked:

```php
function filter_lp_title($title) {
    return 'New title';
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'filter_lp_title', 25 );
```

Comment: It worked by adding "25" can you please tell us what these numbers are related to? Thanks

Comment: `25` is the priority (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/). Why 25, I don't recall it now, it had to be after the Yoast''s filters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use follows code -

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', function($titles){
    return array('title' => 'Custom Title');
});
```

Comment: Please see my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having this issue of the `wp_title` filter not working, I'd suggest adding a higher priority value. The higher priority value will ensure that your filter is executed and not overriden by other filters in your theme or plugins installed. Please see below: (ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

```
  // the 9999999 priority value will force this filter to be executed closer to the end.  A lower number corresponds with earlier execution
  add_filter('wp_title', 'set_custom_title', 9999999, 3);
  function set_custom_title($title, $sep, $seplocation){
    return 'test';
  }
```